# Se repite instrucción por cada llamada a la función

Tags: javascript, datatable

Muy buenas, no sabia muy bién como explicar esto en pocas palabras, pido disculpas.

Tengo un  datatable con un boton, y este boton ejecuta un codigo dentro de la misma funcion. 
Si yo llamo a la funcion varias veces para que me muestre valores distintos,  el codigo del boton al pulsar, se me repite tantas veces como llamadas a la función.
 En este caso el codigo de la función al pulsar el boton es un alert, no entiendo por que repite el alert tantas veces como llamadas a la función al pulsar sobre  el botón.

```
function tar_usr(){ 
    var parametros = {
      "pdt": pdt,
      "of":off
    };

    tableTVG= $('#tblTarVG').DataTable({ 
      "destroy": "true",
      "ajax": {
            "url": "php/sr.php", 
            "type": "POST", 
            "dataSrc": "",
            "data": parametros, 
        },

        "columns": [
            {"defaultContent": "<button type='button'   class='tareaVG  btn btn-primary btn-xs '><span class='glyphicon  glyphicon-zoom-in'></span>", "width": "1%"},
            { "data": "i" },
            { "data": "n" },
            { "data": "d" },
            { "data": "c" },
        ],

    });

    $('#tblTarVG tbody').on('click', 'button.tareaVG', function (){ 
            var formTareaVg = tableTVG.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();

// Este es el codigo que se ejecuta tantas veces como llamo a la función, si yo pulso solo una vez el boton, quiero que solo se ejecute una vez.
            alert("prueba");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que con cada llamada a `tar_usr()` le asignas al botón el evento de click para que haga algo. Creo que tendrías dos opciones:

1. Sacar las líneas del `$('#tblTarVG tbody').on('click'...` fuera de `tar_usr()`
2. Antes de volver a asignar el evento, eliminarlo con `.off()`, añadiendo la siguiente línea antes:

   `$('#tblTarVG tbody').off('click', 'button.tareaVG');`

> Documentación de jQuery para .off(): http://api.jquery.com/off/